# calculate row difference groupwise in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to calculate the difference between two rows groupwise using pandas.

```
| Group | Value | ID |
----------------------
|  M1   | 10    | F1 |
----------------------
|  M1   | 11    | F2 |
----------------------
|  M1   | 12    | F3 |
----------------------
|  M1   | 15    | F4 |
----------------------
```

Example output:

```
----------------------
|  M1   | F3 - F2 | 1 |
----------------------
|  M1   | F4 - F1 | 5 |
```

To calculate the sum I would use pandas.groupby('Group').sum(), but how do you calculate the difference between rows where the row ordering is important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need custom function with [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply) which return `DataFrame` for each group, for select by position is used [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
def f(x):
    #print (x)
    a = x['Value'].iat[2] - x['Value'].iat[1]
    b = x['Value'].iat[3] - x['Value'].iat[0]
    c = x['ID'].iat[2] + ' - ' + x['ID'].iat[1]
    d = x['ID'].iat[3] + ' - ' + x['ID'].iat[0]
    return pd.DataFrame({'Value': [a,b], 'ID':[c,d]})

df = df.groupby('Group').apply(f).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
print (df)

  Group       ID  Value
0    M1  F3 - F2      1
1    M1  F4 - F1      5
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. How would this be updated to select by ID value e.g. "F2" as oposed to they key i.e. iat[2]

Comment: Are always in each group `F1 - F4` ?

Comment: If always `F1` in each group use `e = x.loc[x['ID'] == 'F1', 'Value'].item()`, It is a bit complicated if sometimes `F1` is missing in some group `e = x.loc[x['ID'] == 'F1', 'Value']` and then `e = np.nan if e.empty else e.item()`