# How to calculate the difference between rows depending on value in other column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to calculate the max difference in rows relative to a specific category within a timestamp-group (e.g. full seconds)

I checked similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43953594/calculate-row-difference-groupwise-in-pandas) so far but couldnt figure out how to implement it.

My dataframe looks like:

```
TimeStamp               Category    Value
2020-12-07 07:44:08.679     A       7.40    
2020-12-07 07:44:08.682     B       8.18    
2020-12-07 07:44:08.685     C       6.95    
2020-12-07 07:44:11.271     A       249.30
2020-12-07 07:44:11.272     B       249.75
2020-12-07 07:44:11.273     C       250.58
2020-12-07 07:44:13.746     A       250.18
2020-12-07 07:44:13.747     B       250.78
2020-12-07 07:44:13.748     C       251.33
2020-12-07 07:44:16.225     A       249.87
2020-12-07 07:44:16.226     B       251.48
2020-12-07 07:44:16.227     C       251.43
```

I used this codesnippet to crop it in full second-groups:

```
df['TimeStamp'] = df['TimeStamp'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(microsecond=0))

TimeStamp           Category    Value
2020-12-07 07:44:08     A       7.40    
2020-12-07 07:44:08     B       8.18    
2020-12-07 07:44:08     C       6.95    
2020-12-07 07:44:11     A       249.30
2020-12-07 07:44:11     B       249.75
2020-12-07 07:44:11     C       250.58
2020-12-07 07:44:13     A       250.18
2020-12-07 07:44:13     B       250.78
2020-12-07 07:44:13     C       251.33
2020-12-07 07:44:16     A       249.87
2020-12-07 07:44:16     B       251.48
2020-12-07 07:44:16     C       251.43
```

For example I would like to calculate the max relative difference to `category A`.
This is what I want:

```
TimeStamp             max. Difference
2020-12-07 07:44:08     0.78    
2020-12-07 07:44:11     1.28
2020-12-07 07:44:13     1.15
2020-12-07 07:44:16     1.61
```

So for the first group in `2020-12-07 07:44:08` the calculation would be:

```
abs(7.40 - 8.18) = 0.78
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In your case we can do `groupby`

```
#df['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.TimeStamp,format='%Y-%m-%d% H:%M:%S.%f')
out = df.groupby(df.TimeStamp.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')).\
           apply(lambda x : (x['Value'] - x.loc[x['Category']=='A','Value'].values).abs().max())
Out[15]: 
TimeStamp
2020-12-07 07:44:08    0.78
2020-12-07 07:44:11    1.28
2020-12-07 07:44:13    1.15
2020-12-07 07:44:16    1.61
dtype: float64
```